# Dragging/Resizing a UIImage on the Device

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I'd like to allow a user to add a shape (which would just be a UIImage) onto some sort of canvas, then move and resize it on the screen but I'm not sure how to go about this. Ideally I'd like the basics of a drawing app which can use images from a user's device. Each shape would have an associated position, size and z-index.

The only thing I'm unsure of is how I'd create a bounding box (the one with four blue dots to allow resizing/moving). I have experience with UIKit, and would prefer to keep the majority of the app in this for the time being, but I get the feeling this type of thing might be better suited to Cocos2D or a similar framework.

If anyone has any pointers/open source code I can dig through it would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should look into CALayer, or even CAShapeLayer. I'm just starting to play with them, but I'm pretty sure you can easily get the functionality you want with either. Draw the border in the layer's `drawLayer:inContext:`. Check out the [Quartz2d Guide path drawing section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101) for the functions you need.